# GPflow 2 custom kernel construction: fine upon construction, but kernel of size None in optimization

Tags: python, tensorflow, gpflow, gaussian-process

I'm creating some GPflow models in which I need the observations pre and post of a threshold `x0` to be independent a priori. I could achieve this with just GP models, or with a ChangePoints kernel with infinite steepness, but both solutions don't work well with my future extensions in mind (MOGP in particular).

I figured I could easily construct what I want from scratch, so I made a new Combination kernel object, which uses the appropriate child kernel pre- or post `x0`. This works as intended when I evaluate the kernel on a set of input points; the expected correlations between points before and after threshold are zero, and the rest is determined by the children kernels:

```
import numpy as np
import gpflow
from gpflow.kernels import Matern32
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import tensorflow as tf
from gpflow.kernels import Combination


class IndependentKernel(Combination):

    def __init__(self, kernels, x0, forcing_variable=0, name=None):

        self.x0 = x0
        self.forcing_variable = forcing_variable
        super().__init__(kernels, name=name)

    def K(self, X, X2=None):
        # threshold X, X2 based on self.x0, and construct a joint tensor
        if X2 is None:
            X2 = X

        fv = self.forcing_variable
        mask = tf.dtypes.cast(X[:, fv] >= self.x0, tf.int32)

        X_partitioned = tf.dynamic_partition(X, mask, 2)
        X2_partitioned = tf.dynamic_partition(X2, mask, 2)

        K_pre = self.kernels[0].K(X_partitioned[0], X2_partitioned[0])
        K_post = self.kernels[1].K(X_partitioned[1], X2_partitioned[1])

        zero_block_1 = tf.zeros([K_pre.shape[0], K_post.shape[1]], tf.float64)
        zero_block_2 = tf.zeros([K_post.shape[0], K_pre.shape[1]], tf.float64)
        upper_row = tf.concat([K_pre, zero_block_1], axis=1)
        lower_row = tf.concat([zero_block_2, K_post], axis=1)

        return tf.concat([upper_row, lower_row], axis=0)

    #
    def K_diag(self, X):
        fv = self.forcing_variable
        mask = tf.dtypes.cast(X[:, fv] >= self.x0, tf.int32)

        X_partitioned = tf.dynamic_partition(X, mask, 2)
        return tf.concat([self.kernels[0].K_diag(X_partitioned[0]),
                          self.kernels[1].K_diag(X_partitioned[1])],
                         axis=1)

    #
#


def f(x):
    return np.sin(6*(x-0.7))


x0 = 0.3
n = 100
x = np.linspace(0, 1, n)
sigma = 0.5
y = np.random.normal(loc=f(x), scale=sigma)
fv = 0
X = x[:, None]

kernel = IndependentKernel([Matern32(), Matern32()], x0=x0, name='indep')
x_pred = np.linspace(0, 1, 100)

K = kernel.K(x_pred[:, None])  # <- kernel is evaluated correctly here
```

However, when I want to train a GPflow model with this kernel, I receive the error message `TypeError: Expected int32, got None of type 'NoneType' instead.` This appears to result from the sub-kernel matrices `K_pre` and `K_post` to be of size `(None, 1)`, instead of the expected squares (which they correctly are if I evaluate the kernel 'manually').

```
m = gpflow.models.GPR(data=(X, y[:, None]), kernel=kernel)

gpflow.optimizers.Scipy().minimize(m.training_loss,
                                   m.trainable_variables,
                                   options=dict(maxiter=10000),
                                   method="L-BFGS-B")  # <- K_pre & K_post are of size (None, 1) now?
```

What can I do to make the kernel properly trainable?

I am using GPflow 2.1.3 and TensorFlow 2.4.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is not a GPflow issue but a subtlety of TensorFlow's eager vs graph mode: In **eager** mode (which is the default behaviour when you interact with tensors "manually" as in calling the kernel) `K_pre.shape` works just as expected. In **graph** mode (which is what happens when you wrap code in [`tf.function()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/function), this generally does not always work (e.g. the shape might depend on tf.Variables with None shapes), and you have to use `tf.shape(K_pre)` instead to obtain the *dynamic* shape (that depends on the actual *values* inside the variables). GPflow's Scipy class by default wraps the loss&gradient computation inside `tf.function()` to speed up optimization. If you explicitly turn this off by passing `compile=False` to the minimize() call, your code example runs fine. If you replace the `.shape` attributes with `tf.shape()` calls to fix it properly, it likewise will run fine.

Comment: That solved the issue, marked as solved - thank you!!